# Why do I always get an empty list when I try to return the contents of a mutable list from this module?

Tags: f#

Please, help an F# beginner understand this! I have the following F# code (which I've just created to help me learn, so I realise it's probably terrible):

```
type Account = {
    ID: Guid
    Name: string
};

module Accounts =
    let mutable accounts:Account list = []

    // Why does this always return empty?
    let lst =
        accounts

    let load id =
        accounts |> List.find(fun a-> a.ID = id)

    let save account =
        accounts <- account::accounts

Accounts.save { ID = Guid.NewGuid(); Name = "Account One"}

let id = Guid.NewGuid()

Accounts.save { ID = id; Name = "Account Two"}

let account = Accounts.load id
```

If I write out the value of `account` at this stage (after the above code), I see the `Account` record I expect (Account Two), and if I dump `Accounts.accounts`, I can see that the mutable list contains both `Account` records.

So why does `Account.lst` always return an empty list, even though I can see that the list definitely isn't empty?

Comment: This bug happens to everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `lst` is a value, not a function.

In F#, the technical difference between a value and a function is that a function has parameters, and a value does not.

When you declared `lst`, you didn't give it any parameters, so the compiler understood it as "*I want to take the value of `accounts` at this particular point in time, and refer to that value as `lst` from now on*". So every time you write `lst`, you're not calling a function, but merely referring to that same empty list that was the value of `accounts` at initialization time.

To make `lst` a true function, you need to give it a parameter. And because it doesn't really need any actual data, the natural parameter to give it is the `unit` value - `()`.

```
let lst () = accounts
```

P.S. This whole trickiness ultimately comes from mutating state. Try to avoid it when possible.

Comment: Also, F# lists are immutable. So a normal let binding to a list will always return that same list with those same values.

Comment: Thanks! Now that you've explained it so clearly it seems obvious, but I was pretty puzzled there for a while. 

I realise that keeping everything immutable where possible is generally the way to go, but I just don't know enough yet to implement this example "functionally". I'll get there, though!

Answer (score 4):

Because `lst` is a value not a function. You need to convert it to a function:

```
let lst () =
    accounts
```

then you can call it by:

```
Accounts.lst()
```